# ExtJS 6 - Cannot resolve requirements for theme

Tags: extjs

I created an app using Sencha CMD (6.6.) and it works. Then I copied that folder to another partition (`D:`) and run `sencha workspace init`. When I run it with my local server it works, but `sencha app watch` does not work. 
But that is not the problem since I can run it on the local server. The problem is when I try to generate a new theme. Somehow it has to be compiled with Sencha CMD.

After I ran this command: `sencha generate theme my-theme` it created `my-theme` in ext packages folder.

And when I try to build it, I get this error:

```
Sencha Cmd v6.6.0.13
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : classic (development environment)
[ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for "theme-neutral"!
[ERR]    The following versions cannot be satisfied:
[ERR]       theme-neptune: theme-neutral (No matches!)
[ERR] Cannot resolve package requirements
```

But in my ext folder there are these themes which CMD claims that are missing.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT**

My app.json settings are like this:

```
"builds": {
        "classic": {
            "toolkit": "classic",
            "theme": "my-theme",
            "sass": {
                "generated": {
                    "var": "classic/sass/save.scss",
                    "src": "classic/sass/save"
                }
            }
        },

        "modern": {
            "toolkit": "modern",
            "theme": "theme-material",
            "sass": {
                "generated": {
                    "var": "modern/sass/save.scss",
                    "src": "modern/sass/save"
                }
            }
        }
},
```

Comment: is toolkit classic defined in your package.json? >> "toolkit": "classic",

Comment: Yes. I've edited my question.